# How to print BASE_DIR from settings.py from django app in terminal?

Tags: python, django, terminal

How to print BASE_DIR from settings.py from django app in terminal?
i have the following code in test1.py file:

```
import os
import django
import settings

print BASE_DIR
```

but it prints error:

```
File "test1.py", line 5, in <module>
    print BASE_DIR
NameError: name 'BASE_DIR' is not defined
```

My goal is to write value of BASE_DIR to see what dir is used by Django project.

Comment: can someone explain why i get negative points on this question?

Comment: Because you use django in a wrong way.  If you will try to write real django code in your `test1.py` then this code will fail.

Comment: i am not using it, i am experimenting and learning it.

Comment: Plus points from me - this is a good question for a newb (like me)!

Comment: Me too, as coders we should all be extending our learning by trying to break stuff. Pushing beyond the limits and generally just tinkering. +1 from me

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should print the attribute of the imported module:

```
print settings.BASE_DIR
```

Or import this variable from the module:

```
from settings import BASE_DIR

print BASE_DIR
```

Comment: You should always [import `django.conf.settings`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code). This is a wrapper object around your settings that will fill in any defaults and provides support for site-specific settings. As this is a wrapper object and not a module, you can't use `from django.conf.settings import BASE_DIR` though.

Comment: Nope. If you will try to import `settings` from `django.conf` then `ImproperlyConfigured` exception will be thrown.

Comment: That either means that your settings are improperly configured and you should fix it, or you didn't set the settings module. Both are an easy fix that you should do anyway. That's not a reason to bypass the proper mechanisms Django provides for exactly this.

Answer (score 26):

These commands will help:

```
python manage.py shell
```

Then in python shell type:

```
from django.conf import settings
print(settings.BASE_DIR)
```

Comment: so cool...I always forget about the shell in django. It comes in super handy.