# How to structure the templates folder in django and to use the extends

Tags: django, django-templates, django-settings

I have a folder, templates, structured like below

`/Users/AndyKw/Documents/Python/Else/Yes/templates`

Within `templates`, I have two folders, `admin` and `registration` (see below for the tree)

```
templates (need.html)
|
|-- admin
|
|-- registration (base.html)
```

The file I use `base.html`is in the folder `registration`. It needs to use a file , `need.html` in the folder `templates` with the `extends` command.

Question is the following:

- How do I configure in the settings.py the `templates` parameter to use `registration` as the main folder and
  through `base.html` to reach by using `extends` the file `need.html` in the `templates` folder?

One possible solution would be to invert the path, put `need.html` in the `registration` folder and put the `base.html`
in the `templates` folder but the dev team seems to be quite unbending on this solution, this would be the less favourable way.

Any ideas/tips are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In settings.py:

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],
        ...
    }
]
```

Then in need.html:

```
<head>
  <!-- common headers for all templates -->
  {% block head %}
  {% endblock %}
</head>

<body>
  <!-- common body for all template -->
  {% block body %}
  {% endblock %}
</body>
```

Then in all your templates:

```html
{% extends "need.html" %}

{% block head %}
<!-- headers here -->
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<!-- body here -->
{% endblock  %}
```

Comment: Hi @Daniel, how am I sure that the `BASE_DIR` is the correct one e.g it won'r do something like `/Users/AndyKw/Documents/Python/Else/No/` or even `/Users/AndyKw/Documents/Python/Bim/`?

Comment: BASE_DIR should be automatically set when you start a new django project - just dont change it - for example in django3.0+ it looks like this in your settings.py file:
`BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent`

Comment: got my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41301143/2572645. Ty @daniel

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do the following:

In the settings.py inside TEMPLATES change DIRS parameter to:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/registration'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

This way you can use {% extends "need.html" %} inside registration/base.html.

Now, if you want to load all the base.html content below the extends then do the following:

- base.html file:

  ```
  {% extends "need.html" %}

  {% block base_content %}

     <html content of base.html>

  {% endblock base_content %}
  ```
- need.html file:

  ```
  <html content of need.html>
  {% block base_content %}{% endblock base_content %}
  ```